# Conceptual Understanding of Non-Linear Optimization Problem

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I'm in non-linear optimization, and I'm having trouble wrapping my head around what this problem is asking me for. If anyone could help with a conceptual explanation (not an answer!), it'd be greatly appreciated.

To approximate a function *g* over the interval [0,1] by a polynomial *p* of degree *n* (or less), we minimize the criterion:

[image]

where [image]. Find the equations satisfied by the optimal coefficients [image].

So obviously *g(x)* is the function I want to approximate, using(?) the polynomial *p(x)*. But I'm not even sure where the equations I'm supposed to find come from. Are they just the equations that *g(x)* must be for this approximation to be successful? This is probably totally simple, but I'm lost.

Answer (score 0):

Your polynomials look like what you wrote: $p(x)=a_nx^n+\cdots+a_0$.  You want to minimize $f(a)$.  This means you have an $n+1$ dimensional unconstrained space in which to find the values of $a$.  Let's look at $n=0$ to see if it helps:

$$\min_{a_0} f(a) = \int_0^1[g(x)-a_0]^2\,dx$$

The necessary condition is a stationary point, i.e., $$\frac{\partial f(a)}{\partial a_0}=0.$$
Can you calculate $$\frac{\partial f(a)}{\partial a_0}=\frac{\partial}{\partial a_0}\int_0^1[g(x)-a_0]^2\,dx?$$